# How to make a component in React JS to have it's on values and functionalities separately from the same component in a page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm kinda new to react js, I would be grateful if someone could help me out.
The idea is to have some items (foods) as components and add them to your shopping list and eventually post the final purchase bag to the server.
I have made a component to use as my item card and created a function to add and increase the amount of that item. but when I try to work with the component it affects all the other components.
this is the result of my output. When I add and increase food in a component the other components' amounts continue from the one I added last.
[image]
how can I separate the functionally of the same components on a page?

here is the code that I wrote:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
var Amount = 0;

function FoodItem(props) {
  const [mainDivActivated, mainDivSetStyle] = useState("FoodItemMainContainer");
  const [descriptionDivActivated, descriptionSetStyle] =useState("FoodDescription");
  const [addButtonDivDisplay, addButtonSetStyle] = useState("PositionReletive");
  const [trashButtonDivDisplay, trashButtonSetStyle] = useState("PositionReletive DisplayNone");
  const [amountNumber, setAmountNumber] = useState();
  var activate = 0;

  function OnclickAddToAmount() {
    Amount++;
    setAmountNumber(Amount);
  }
  function OnclickRemoveFromAmount() {
    Amount--;
    setAmountNumber(Amount);
  }

  function OnclickActivateEvent() {
    activateItem();
    OnclickAddToAmount();
  }
  function activateItem() {
    mainDivSetStyle("FoodItemMainContainer PrimaryBackgroundGradientColor");
    descriptionSetStyle("FoodDescriptionActivated");
    addButtonSetStyle("PositionReletive DisplayNone");
    trashButtonSetStyle("PositionReletive");
  }
  function OnclickDeactivateEvent() {
    deactivateItem();
    OnclickRemoveFromAmount();
  }
  function deactivateItem() {
    mainDivSetStyle("FoodItemMainContainer");
    descriptionSetStyle("FoodDescription");
    addButtonSetStyle("PositionReletive");
    trashButtonSetStyle("PositionReletive DisplayNone");
  }

  return (
    <div className={mainDivActivated}>
      <div className="FoodItemContainer">
        <div>
          <div className="FontSizeXL">{props.foodName}</div>
          <div className={descriptionDivActivated}>{props.foodDescription}</div>
        </div>
        <div className="PositionReletive">
          <img
            className="VerticallyAndHorizontallyCentered FoodMenuImageCss"
            src="/images/temptestpictures/foodImage.jpg"
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
        <div className="PositionReletive FoodItemPriceCss">
          <div className="FontSizeXL">Price : {props.foodPrice}</div>
        </div>
        <div className={addButtonDivDisplay}>
          <div
            onClick={() => OnclickActivateEvent()}
            className="FontSizeXL PrimaryBackgroundGradientColor ColorWhite VerticallyAndHorizontallyCentered WidthFull HorizontallyCenteredText FoodItemAddBtn"
          >
            Add
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={trashButtonDivDisplay}>
          <div className="VerticallyAndHorizontallyCentered WidthFull HorizontallyCenteredText FoodItemAddBtn">
            <div className="AddOrRemoveFoodIconContainer">
              {Amount<2 ? (
                <span onClick={() => OnclickDeactivateEvent()}className="icon-trashcan AddOrRemoveFoodIcon"></span>
              ) : (
                <span onClick={() => OnclickRemoveFromAmount()}className="icon-minus AddOrRemoveFoodIcon"></span>
              )}
              <div className="FontSizeXL AddOrremoveNumber">{Amount}</div>
              <span onClick={() => OnclickAddToAmount()}className="icon-plus AddOrRemoveFoodIcon"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default FoodItem;
```

Comment: Why is `Amount` declared globally instead of as state? That said, the code here is syntactically invalid so I'm not sure how this is running at all.

Comment: Well, the counter gets stock at 1 if I declare "Amount" inside of the main function. what do you suggest?

Comment: Instead of initializing `Amount` in the `FoodItem` component, maintain an array or map of `Amounts` in the parent component's state along with a key. Then, pass the key's `Amount` value to each `FoodItem` component. This way, the amounts won't be reset. Check this on [lifting state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: I'm suggesting: wouldn't it make sense for each `Food` component to have its own `amount` counter as state? If they all share one counter then... they all share one counter!

Comment: @Bms bharadwaj
thanks, kinda new to this whole react js thingy :D . I'll check it out right away

Comment: @ggorlen
I know, that's what I want to avoid and don't know how :(

Comment: How about `const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0)` just like all the other state variables you created? On click, `setAmount(prevAmount => prevAmount + 1)`